# How to return a FileResult AND RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Action that returns a FileResult via `View(...)`.  This works well.

Ideally I would like to be able to somehow return a file and then redirect to another action (or somehow do both simultaneously).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done by a javascript code in client side which run after download started, you can see the pattern in many website, most notably Microsoft download center.

Comment: It would be nice to see the code syntax for this. I have the same problem. I want to Save As a file and RedirectToAction right afterwards.